Placing 1x2 or 2x1 tiles on r x c matrix to achieve maximum sum of covered cells
How can you find the maximum possible sum of values by optimally placing tiles in a matrix rxc where each cell has an integer value?
The goal is to maximize the sum by covering cells with 1x2 or 2x1 tiles.

Consider location (n, k), we have 3 cases:

Place a 1 * 2 tiles
Place a 2 * 1 tiles
Place nothing

For example:
Case 1:
????
????
??xx

Case 2:
????
???x
???x

Case 3:
????
????
???.

For case 2, we will record which grid in the next line we have already taken so that we can solve this question by dp.
We can define:
sol(x, y, right_incomplete, up_incompletes) 
  is the maximum of point(x, y) in the condition of right_incomplete and up_incomples

So for point (x, y):
if right_incomplete(which means we a place 1*2 tile in (x, y+1)), we must close this tile at (x, y)
if up_incomplete(which means we a place 2*1 tile in (x+1, y)), we must close this tile at (x, y)
if both right_incomplete and up_incomplete, means no feasible solution.
If it is not right_incomplete and up_incomplete, we have three choices: place 1 * 2, place 2 * 1, or do nothing. With each choice, we will come to a smaller question.
We take an example:

The Red lines mean the up_incompletes which have k grids.
The Blue line means the right_incomplete.
The arrows mean there is an incomplete otherwise no.
Now, we are considering the dark gray grid. Based on our up_incompletes information, we should close this incomplete at this grid, so we have only 1 choice here.
After we do that, then we come to:

We take another example:

Since there is no incomplete from this grid, we have three choices, which are:
Choice 1, do nothing:

Choice 2, place a 1 * 2 tile, so there will be a right_incomplete for our next grid:

Choice 3, place a 2 * 1 tile, so there will be an up_incomplete for the grid next row with the same column:

In summary:
sol(x, y, right_incomplete, up_incompletes) = 
  max(all_possible_solutions) + take_x_y?array[x][y]:0

And by this way, we can achieve an O(n*k*2^k) solution.
You can check my code for more details:
MAX_ANS = 10**100


def sol(matrix):
    mem = {}

    def _sol(x, y, up_incomplete, right_incomplete):
        p = (x, y, up_incomplete, right_incomplete)
        if up_incomplete[-1] and right_incomplete:
            return -MAX_ANS
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            if up_incomplete[-1] or right_incomplete:
                return matrix[x][y]
            else:
                return 0
        if mem.get(p) is not None:
            return mem[p]
        ans = 0
        if y != 0:
            next_x, next_y = x, y - 1
        else:
            next_x, next_y = x - 1, len(matrix[0]) - 1

        if right_incomplete:
            new_up_incomplete = tuple([False]) + up_incomplete[:-1]
            ans = max(ans, matrix[x][y] + _sol(next_x, next_y, new_up_incomplete, False))
        elif up_incomplete[-1]:
            new_up_incomplete = tuple([False]) + up_incomplete[:-1]
            ans = max(ans, matrix[x][y] + _sol(next_x, next_y, new_up_incomplete, False))
        else:
            if y != 0:
                new_up_incomplete = tuple([False]) + up_incomplete[:-1]
                ans = max(ans, matrix[x][y] + _sol(next_x, next_y, new_up_incomplete, True))
            if x != 0:
                new_up_incomplete = tuple([True]) + up_incomplete[:-1]
                ans = max(ans, matrix[x][y] + _sol(next_x, next_y, new_up_incomplete, False))

            new_up_incomplete = tuple([False]) + up_incomplete[:-1]
            ans = max(ans, _sol(next_x, next_y, new_up_incomplete, False))

        mem[p] = ans
        return ans

    return _sol(len(matrix) - 1, len(matrix[0]) - 1, tuple([False]*len(matrix[0])), False)


test_1 = [
    [1, 2, 3]
    , [4, -5, -6]
]

test_2 = [
     [2, 6, 3, 1]
    , [6, 5, 6, 1]
    , [2, -6, 2, 1]
]

test_3 = [
     [10, -5]
    , [-5, 2]
]

print(sol(test_1))
print(sol(test_2))
print(sol(test_3))

